# MongoDB returns empty array

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra

I have a MongoDB that spits record onto a webpage

```
require 'mongo'
require 'json'

connection = Mongo::Connection.new
db = connection.db("salemDB")
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("salemDB")
newsCollection = db["news"]

require 'sinatra'
set:port, 2222
get '/' do
    redirect 'index.html'
end

get "/checkMail" do
  newsCollection.find_one({}, {}).to_a.to_json
end

get "/:id" do
 newsCollection.find("_id" => params[:id]).to_a.to_json
end
```

**/checkmail outputs this**

(formatted for reading pleasure)

```
[
   [
      "_id",
      {
         "$oid":"50880c8564a15e2631000001"
      }
   ],
   [
      "date",
      "2012-10-24T17:42:54+02:00"
   ],
   [
      "subject",
      "This is a piece of news"
   ]
]
```

**/50880c8564a15e2631000001 outputs this**

```
[]
```

Why won't it give my object back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the id actually is not a string or Integer it's an `BSON::ObjectId`, so you have to query with one of those.

This should work

```
newsCollection.find("_id" => BSON::ObjectId(params[:id])).to_a.to_json
```